# Link gets cut of within a body of mailto

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have a javascript code that generates emails with links in the body.

Some of the links have spaces within the link, so the link gets cut of.

[image]

I tried replacing the spaces with the asacii code but it didn't work.

```
var lineBreak = "%0D%0A";

function GetMailToInfo(attachment, body) {

    attachment = attachment ? attachment.replace(" ","%0D%0A") + lineBreak + lineBreak : "";
    body += attachment + signature;
    window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?subject=" + subject() + "&body=" + body;
}
```

Any idea on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent` to properly escape special characters in URLs:

```
window.location.href = 
    "mailto:"   + encodeURIComponent(emailTo) + 
    "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject()) + 
    "&body="    + encodeURIComponent(body);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely because `String.replace` only replaces the first occurrence when using a `string` as the first parameter. See [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

I would suggest either looping:

```
while (attachment.indexOf(" ") >= 0) {
    attachment = attachment.replace(" ", "%0A%0D");
}
```

Or using `RegEx` to perform a pattern-based replacement.

However, Quentin's solution is the proper way to go about encoding strings to be safe for URI use. My answer here is for the more general case where it may not be a URI string.

Comment: Thank you for your help!